# Does this guarantee only one initialization of the singleton class

Tags: java, static, singleton

```
void build(){
  while(true){
    Builder builder = new Builder();
    ...
  }
}

class Builder{
   private final Store store = null;

   public Builder(){
     store = Store.getInstance();
   }
}
```

The 'Store' is implemented as a standard singleton class, as shown here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

I hope the Store object will be initialized only once and in the 'while' loop the same 'store' object will be created and returned inside the multiple "builder" objects due to the whole loop.  Is this guaranteed? What about if defining "store" as a static variable of Builder?

Comment: If `Store` is a singleton, why do you even need to save an instance of it? Why not have your code use `Store.getInstance()` directly?

Comment: Why not just put the `Builder builder = new Builder();` on the outside of the `while` loop. And if needed, on the inside do `builder = new Builder();` on the inside? Or is this a puzzle question?

Comment: If it's a singleton *object*, it doesn't matter how many *references* you have to it. Also, note that since Java 5, a singleton can be implemented by a single-element enum.

Comment: @Mureinik In this case it's not any better but if dependency injection were used, there's plenty of reasons for not accessing the singleton directly. First and foremost, testability.

Comment: @Mureinik, because in my same class, I need to refer to the Store object more than 1 time. By storing it as one variable, I don't have to write "Store.getInstance()" multiple times. Does this make sense?

Comment: @JoshHeaps, my code is incomplete, actually there is a parameter to the Builder's constructor and I omitted here. That is why it has to be in the loop.

Comment: Your class `Builder` won't compile as presented. Did you try to compile it? You cannot assign to a `final` variable but once.

Comment: @user697911 I don't agree that avoiding ​multiple calls to `getInstance` makes any sense. Then again, I don't agree that a singleton should have a `getInstance` method anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I hope the Store object will be initialized only once and in the
>   'while' loop the same 'store' object will be created and returned
>   inside the multiple "builder" objects due to the whole loop. Is this
>   guaranteed?

Yes, there will be a single instance of the `Store` object if it is implemented as a `Singleton` and this is due to the keyword `static`.

> What about if defining "store" as a static variable of Builder?

You may or may not do this depending on your needs but if you really need a `Singleton` ([which in many cases you don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons)), you may want to store it in a separate class, just to make the code more structured.

Also, you don't need `private final Store store = null;`, as you may always access (the same instance) of `Store` using `Store.getInstance()`.

Answer (score 0):

Because the instance of `Store` is static within its class, calling `getInstance()` should not create a new `Store`. `getInstance()` will simply return you the `private static final Store instance` that you should have inside your singleton.

From the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) page:

> An implementation of the singleton pattern must: **ensure that only one instance of the singleton class ever exists**; and
>   provide global access to that instance.

Comment: @user697911 Assuming you've correctly created the singleton, yes!

Comment: If wikipedia is right, I am right too :) I basically copied.

Comment: @user697911 when in doubt, wikipedia ;)

Comment: Does it make a real difference between "private static Store store = Store.getInstance()" and "private final Store store = Store.getInstance() "?

Comment: @user697911 I don't think so, but I think the point is that you aren't supposed to change the instance, so it might as well be `final`. Either way it needs to be `static` though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145153/discussion-between-user697911-and-chris-gilardi).